# Get my overwritten Excel back

Tags: microsoft-excel, file-recovery

I have an old Excel file in the USB drive, unfortunately, i accidentally copied it into a folder that contains a newer version with the same name and overwrote the new version. I want to get my old excel back and can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your chances to recover your file are rather slim. I'm not 100% sure I understood your problem. Do you want the newer version back?

If so, you're pretty much out of luck, unless there exists a shadow copy of some sorts (only provided in Windows 7 IIRC and by default only for stuff under `C:\Users`).

Right click the folder where the new file has been, open the properties, and look whether there is some tab for previous versions.

Under Windows 8/8.1 there might be an automatic backup with the old newer file, but once again this is not guaranteed.

You can still try to use a tool such as [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva/download) (Freeware) and look for old copies of the file, but this is not guaranteed to find an overwritten file (also depends on how you copied or moved the file).

Comment: Thank for your totally free software named Recuva, As the data in my Excel is very important to me, so i got a professional Microsoft Excel Recovery tool do the work. i search and find it in Google. here is the helpful link..http://drm-assistant.com/datarescue/restore-overwritten-word-excel-powerpoint-file.html

Comment: This question, and the above comment, strike me as suspicious. Together with the fact that user69697 claims to have been able to recover the data - which seems unlikely - there is something about user69697's language that makes me think that the link in the comment above should be avoided. I actually followed the link and downloaded the software, and got all sorts of warnings from antivirus software at every stage of that process.